# MSBuild ver.16 runs hundreds of MSBuild processes when MaxNodeCount is greater than 1

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, msbuild

We have an application, which builds and prepares a "deploy package" of our ASP.NET applications. It had references to the .NET Framework MSBuild, which was working fine. Few weeks ago we started to use VS2019 instead of VS2015. Because of some NuGet packages we had to update this application with latest MSBuild, which is now part of the VS and not in GAC anymore. I did that using [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/updating-an-existing-application?view=vs-2019). And then the fun began... :/ I found out that the problem lies in *BuildParameters.MaxNodeCount* property:

- If I set it's value to 1, everything works fine but far slower than before the update.
- If value is set to something greater than 1 (I set it to *Environment.ProcessorCount*), literaly hundreds of MSBuild processes are started. Sometimes it works but most of the time it fails with *outofmemory* exception. Sometimes even OS collapses and needs to be restarted.

[Picture of lots of MSBuild processes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipeT2.png)

[Picture of MSBuild error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jol67.png)

Before the update *BuildProperties.MaxNodeCount* was set to *Environment.ProcessorCount* and everything worked fine.

Any idea what could cause this kind of behaviour? Why property MaxNodeCount is not taken into account?

**Edit 1:**

Code, that invokes MSBuild API:

```
Dictionary<string, string> GlobalProperty = new Dictionary<string, string>();
GlobalProperty.Add("Platform", "Any CPU");
GlobalProperty.Add("Configuration", "Release");
GlobalProperty.Add("TargetFrameworkVersion", "v4.8");
GlobalProperty.Add("DeployOnBuild", "true");
GlobalProperty.Add("PublishProfile", "passed_as_input_parameter");
GlobalProperty.Add("AspnetMergePath", "passed_as_input_parameter");

BuildResult buildResult;
FileLogger fl = new FileLogger()
{
    Parameters = @"logfile=log_file_path;append=true",
    Verbosity = LoggerVerbosity.Normal
};

BuildParameters bp = new BuildParameters()
{
    Loggers = new List<Microsoft.Build.Framework.ILogger> { fl }.AsEnumerable(),
    DetailedSummary = false,
    OnlyLogCriticalEvents = false,
    ShutdownInProcNodeOnBuildFinish = true,
    MaxNodeCount = Environment.ProcessorCount
};           
            
BuildRequestData br;
br = new BuildRequestData(projectFileName, GlobalProperty, null, new string[] { "Clean", "Rebuild" }, null);

buildResult = BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.Build(bp, br);
```

Comment: I hade the same problem appear out of nowhere. Glad to see I'm not going mad yet.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am banging my head to the table for two days straight with no usable results... :( And there is no info on uncle google on this topic (at least I am not aware of any).

Comment: I haven't. I'm back to remote working as well so I can't really test it since Windows entirely dies when that happens... I have uninstalled VS2019, leaving only MSBuild 15.0 and the problem still occurs. Another symptom I think is related is that building the same project file several times, even with different project collections and build managers, makes item data carry over between invocations and causes build errors and general nonsense. I have fallen back to single-threaded building until someone else can chime in.